# how to make whats app multiple login accounts in one browser

Tags: browser, whatsapp

I just want one browser that can support multiple whats app account that can messaging and chatting for purpose. i have at least ten whats app account can run one browser with any extra extension tool or something else.

Can any one have idea???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yes, I just found One Chrome Extension like All in One messenger that can manage multiple whats app account on one browser can u have any suggestion that same as other extensions works.